# Не авторизован 401

Tags: c#

Есть код соединения с вк

```
string resultPage = "";
                 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2273&client_secret=hHbZx&username=" + textBox2.Text + "&password=" + textBox1.Text);
                 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                 using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true))
                 {
                     resultPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
                     sr.Close();
                 }
```

Если данные верные, то всё норм. Если нет, то пишет ошибку 401 программа зависает и выкидывает из неё.   Я знаю, что это означает, что типа не авторизован. Ошибку показывает

тут

```
 HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

Как можно сделать что бы приложение не закрывалось? Из-за ошибки 401.  А например просто значение  resultPage стало пустым

Comment: про обработку исключений что-нибудь слышали?

Comment: Слышать слышал. Нашел даже вот это http://andrey.moveax.ru/post/asp-net-mvc-error-handling-library.aspx

Comment: начните с любого нормального учебника по C#, найдите там раздел про обработку исключений, и внимательно прочтите его (а лучше прочитайте всю книгу). Статья, которую вы привели, вряд ли вам поможет, если вы не знакомы с базовыми принципами обработки исключений. Да она, собственно, и не про это

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для консольного приложения: с обработкой исключения.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string resultPage = "";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://oauth.vk.com/token?grant_type=password&client_id=2273&client_secret=hHbZx&username=" + "textBox2.Text" + "&password=" + "textBox1.Text");
            try
            {
                HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8, true))
                {
                    resultPage = sr.ReadToEnd();
                    sr.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Просто выводится ошибка в консоль. Также можно сделать для Вашего приложения.